# Bash recursively replace many spaces on names

Tags: linux, bash, sed, rename, batch-rename

Can anyone recommend a safe solution to recursively replace spaces with underscores in file and directory names starting from a given root directory? For example,

```
$ tree
.
|-- a dir
|   `-- file with spaces.txt
`-- b dir
    |-- another file with spaces.txt
    `-- yet another file with spaces.pdf
```

becomes:

```
$ tree
.
|-- a_dir
|   `-- file_with_spaces.txt
`-- b_dir
    |-- another_file_with_spaces.txt
    `-- yet_another_file_with_spaces.pdf
```

I've copied the question by another user which is the main question, but I need to add another issue:

I'm using the solution below:

```
$ find -depth -name '* *' -execdir rename " " "_" {} +;
```

It works, but only replaces the first whitespace found on an item (dir or file). Any ideas about how to make a loop to seek for spaces and stop when they're all gone?

Comment: The solution below worked for me. I just added the -depth option. Without it the parent directory has its name changed and the process crashes. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have `rename` available, or if you're not sure about which version you have, here's a way to achieve that:

```
find . -depth -name '* *' -execdir bash -c 'for i; do mv "$i" "${i// /_}"; done' _ {} +
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
find . -depth -name '* *' -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' {} +
```

Comment: Yes indeed, bad copy/paste error from question. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to assume a different version (the Perl script) of `rename` than what the OP is using (which appears to be the version from the `util-linux-ng` package.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution without `rename`

```
find -type d -name "* *" -print | awk '{print;gsub(" ","_",$0);print}' | xargs -r -n2 -d "\n" mv
find         -name "* *" -print | awk '{print;gsub(" ","_",$0);print}' | xargs -r -n2 -d "\n" mv
```

I assume there are no `\n` in your file names.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the `IFS` variable to make a for-loop use line endings instead of spaces:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") ; for file in $(find . -type f) ; do mv -v $file ${file// /_} ; done
```

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html

Comment: changing IFS causes problems such as 'break' or 'exit' not working any longer, thus the loop continues until it finishes.